# How to apply summarise_each to all columns except one?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am analyzing a set of data with many columns (almost 30 columns). I want to group data based on two columns and apply sum and mean functions to all the columns except timestamp. 
How would I use summarise_each on all columns except timestamp?

This is the draft code I have but it obviously not correct. Plus it generates and error because it can not apply Sum to POSIXt data type (Error: 'sum' not defined for "POSIXt" objects)

```
features <- dataset %>% 
  group_by(X, Y) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(mean,sum)) %>%
  arrange(TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: Use `select()` before summarising maybe? Although you are going to not have a `TIMESTAMP` any more because it has more rows than your summary.

Comment: Perfect. worked fine. I wish you'd added it as an answer so I could select it as the best answer

Comment: You can simply do `summarise_each(funs(mean, sum), -TIMESTAMP)`

Comment: Thanks @StevenBeaupré that's actually easier :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try `summarise_each(funs(mean,sum), -TIMESTAMP)` to exclude `TIMESTAMP` from the summarisation.

Comment: why does this not work for the current function `summarise_all`?

Comment: try -c(TIMESTAMP) @HNSKD

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot add another answer. I think it this question was closed for a bad reason; the answer you're looking for is not on the referenced page. Anyway, for the new `dplyr` (>= 0.8.0) you need to use `summarise_at(vars(-TIMESTAMP), ~mean)` to summarise on all but the TIMESTAMP variable.