# R summarise_all() but exclude several columns

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I use the function summarise_all (from dplyr), but exclude several columns?

I saw some other topics on Stackoverflow, but they didn't gave an workable solution ([How to apply summarise_each to all columns except one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624833/how-to-apply-summarise-each-to-all-columns-except-one)).

The select() option is not really a solution, because I'm dealing with a lot of columns.

This is my code:

```
data_frame1 <- data_frame %>% 
  group_by(visitor_id) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(sum), - hit_time_gmt, - visit_start_pagename)
```

The error that I get:

```
Error in eval_bare(dot$expr, dot$env) : object 'hit_time_gmt' not found
```

And I don't get it, because when I check data_frame, I see that the columns hit_time_gmt and visit_start_pagename are existing.

Comment: put those inside `vars` and use `summarise_at`

Comment: also see `summarize_if`

Comment: or `summarize_at`

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I'm doing it right. But is this what you had in mind, @akrun: 

data_frame1 <- data_frame %>% 
  group_by(visitor_id) %>%
  summarise_at(- hit_time_gmt, - visit_start_pagename, funs(sum))

Comment: I meant `data_frame %>% group_by(visitor_id) %>% summarise_at(vars(-hit_time_gmt, -visit_start_pagename), funs(sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))`  The `na.rm` is to take account for the NA values if any

Comment: Once again, you saved me.

Comment: Alternatively you could use `data.table` which is faster anyway. Using `.SDcols` should solve your problem. For multiple column names (a hundered, say), you could always `grep` or use `setdiff` over `colnames`.